# Google Maps animateToCameraPosition Only Sometimes Working

Tags: ios, google-maps, cllocationmanager, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I have already asked a similar question on here before and failed to get an answer but at the time I didn't know the exact issue but now I have pinpointed it.

When I leave my view in my app as in going into another view then going back to my main view, sometimes my animateToCameraPosition is not positioning me on my location and just leaves the user at the default location. I have tried everything and researched online and nothing seems to fix this.

Code is below.

Thanks.

```
BOOL firstLocationUpdate;
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        firstLocationUpdate= NO;  


        self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;


            self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;

            self.mapView.settings.compassButton = NO;


            self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = NO;


            self.mapView.delegate = self;

        [self.mapView addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:NULL];

            self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.mapView.settings.rotateGestures = NO;
            self.mapView.settings.tiltGestures = NO;

    }


    - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                          ofObject:(id)object
                            change:(NSDictionary *)change
                           context:(void *)context {
        if (!firstLocationUpdate) {

            NSLog(@"LOCATION MASTER");
            // If the first location update has not yet been recieved, then jump to that
            // location.
            firstLocationUpdate = YES;
            CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
          //  self.mapView.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate
                   //                                          zoom:14];
            CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];


             GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:location.coordinate.latitude
                                                                  longitude:location.coordinate.longitude
                                                                     zoom:17.0];
              [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
             latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
             longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
             NSLog(@"latitude = %g", latitude);

             NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
             [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                if(placemarks.count){

                  self.address.text = [placemarks[0] name];
            // NSLog(@"test");
            //streetNumberLabel.text = [placemarks[0] subThoroughfare];
            //streetLabel.text = [placemarks[0] thoroughfare];
            //neighborhoodLabel.text = [placemarks[0] subLocality];
              }
             }];



        }
```